# How to get table cell to use minimum height when using rowspan?

Tags: html, html-table

My html table looks like

```
-------
|  |  |
|  |--|
|  |  |
-------
```

The problem is, when the height of the column on the left side, gets too big, the top right cell's height expands too much.

How can I set it so that the height of the top right cell is only big enough to show whats inside it? Basically use minimum height to show everything inside. The bottom right cell, should have a valign set to top too.

Comment: Great, what's your HTML? And what particular heights would you like to set as the 'minimum'?

Comment: I actually don't want to hard code a height, isn't possible to set it to cover whats inside only?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had image in the big cell, text in the top right and image on the bottom right. It appeared that I had vertical-align property set to baseline for table, tr and td in my CSS. I do not understand why but removing it was enough to solve my problem. I hope this can be useful to some.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
table.spanned tr:first-child {height:100%}
```

Result:
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zqDDu/4/

Comment: You jsfiddle actual shows this working the wrong way... bottom-right is gettring fixed and top-right is growing. This fixes it though: `table.spanned tr:first-child {height:100%}`

Comment: @musefan I'm not sure I get what you're saying. The CSS you mention is already in the fiddle, so how does it fix it?